# Clickable div with z-index

Tags: css

I want to make the same design below

[image]

But I have a problem with the floating div which is the camera icon.
It should be clickable. I put z-index so it will be on top of the image that will change. I want to make all div to be clickable.

Hope you guys can help me.

Thanks!

here's my code

```
<article class="RegistrationInfo__Section media">
    <div class="RegistrationInfo__Section--image media-left">
      <div class="field">
        <span class="file-bg">
          <span
            class="icon is-large"
            v-if="formObject.image"
          >
            <img v-if src="~@/assets/images/camera.png">
          </span>

          <img v-else src="~@/assets/images/camera.png">
        </span>
        <div class="file is-boxed">
          <label class="file-label">
            <input
              class="file-input"
              type="file"
              name="image"
              ref="input"
              @change="validateAndProcessImage"
            >
            <span class="file-cta">
              <span class="file-icon">
                <img
                  v-if="formObject.image"
                  :src="`/api/files/${formObject.image}`"
                >
                <img v-else src="~@/assets/images/profile_off.png">
              </span>
            </span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <p v-if="formErrors.imageFiles" class="help is-danger">{{ formErrors.imageFiles[0] }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
```

Here's my SCSS file.

```
.RegistrationInfo {
@at-root #{&}__Section {
@at-root #{&}--image {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  .field {
    position: relative;

    .file-bg {
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 1;
      right: -10px;
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;

      .icon i {
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: auto;
      }
    }

    .file {
      &.is-boxed {
        .file-icon {
          height: 128px;
          width: 128px;
          margin-right: 0;
        }
        .file-cta {
          padding: 0;
          border-radius: 50%;
          justify-content: center;

          img {
            height: 128px;
            width: 128px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: top;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    .help {
      max-width: 128px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Seeing a working MVCE with rendered html and processed styles would be far more helpful in this case, Alyssa. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be with the z-index you did set.

By default, all page elements have a z-index of 1 unless otherwise specified. Provided that `.file-bg` is your camera icon, changing the z-index to 2 would make your div clickable.

Comment: Thanks but I already figured out. I have another worked around. I make the height of the input type 100% then I put opacity to zero so it will not be visible.